# Are native methods (JNI) always compiled?

Tags: java, jvm, java-native-interface

I noticed [here](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/hotspot/share/runtime/sharedRuntime.cpp#L3031) that when `native` methods are called, a wrapper is generated. However, it appears that this wrapper is only generated when the method is compiled. So, my question is:
Can `native` methods be interpreted, and not compiled (**from the java perspective**)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can native methods be interpreted, and not compiled (from the java perspective)?

Yes, see e.g. here where the interpreter stub is being generated (in `TemplateInterpreterGenerator::generate_native_entry`): https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/01c0d5dd0a4f7587288219bad8ed4648f4e456ce/src/hotspot/cpu/x86/templateInterpreterGenerator_x86.cpp#L793

The main difference between the compiled and interpreted stub, is that the interpreter stub handles *all* interpreted native calls (well, there are 2 stubs: one for `synchronized` methods, and one for regular methods), while the compiled wrapper is specialized for just one method.

For the interpreter stub, different parameter and return types are handled with an out-of-line call to a 'signature handler' and 'result handler'.